# Electromagnetic equations in vector form without convenient symmetry

Tags: electric-fields

Vector calculus is essential for an understanding of electricity and magnetism. In the real world, how are detailed vector equations for electric fields generated? It seems to me that unless you can achieve this, you can only work with situations that have near perfect symmetry.

Comment: What do you mean by "detailed vector equations"? Do you mean the (Maxwell) equations of motion, or the solutions to them?

Comment: Like if you describe a electric field as a vector equation <f(x,y,z),g(x,y,z),h(x,y,z)>

Comment: That's not an equation (hint: it doesn't have an equals sign) but in any case, there's multiple types of equations ─ definitions (like $\mathbf E(\mathbf r)=(E_x(\mathbf r), E_y(\mathbf r), E_z(\mathbf r))$), equations of motions (like $\nabla \times \mathbf E=-\partial_t \mathbf B$) and their solutions (like $\mathbf E(\mathbf r,t)=(E_0 \cos(kz-\omega t),0,0)$), among others, and until and unless you clarify which one you're asking about, this post is unanswerable.